# Toolbar animation with fade off and fade in

Tags: android, android-layout

How to achieve this?

1. Toolbar is not visible when screen is shown.
2. When user scrolls up, toolbar will start appearing with its child view and disappear when scrolls down again like in glass door app.(job details screen)
3. The scroll also must be smoothed because layout behaviour in Appbar layout causes non smooth scroll.

All questions in stack overflow always consider hiding of toolbar view when we scroll up. My case is different like in glass door app.

Is this possible to achieve without library?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the [*Glassdoor*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glassdoor.app&hl=en) app is using a modified version of the [`CollapsingToolbarLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html). You do need to include the design support and appcompat v7 libraries:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

And you can set up the layout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppBarOverlay" android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary" app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/collapsing_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/collapsing_layout_height"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" app:popupTheme="@style/PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Your scrolling content goes here -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This will make the `collapsing_image` disappear underneath the `toolbar` when the content is scrolled upwards.

Anything is achievable without a library, you would just have to write a lot of your own code.